# WPF Intensive UI processing causes ContextSwitchDeadlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Charting application. Basically, the user enters data from files and the application charts the data. When the number of points in the chart becomes very large I get a ContextSwitchDeadlock error that says

`The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x23cda8 to COM context 0x23cf18 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.`

Now, I realize this is because the UI thread is not supposed to be busy for that long but I'm not clear on what my options are because the entire time is spent adding components to the UI. I cant use a `BackGroundWorker` if I'm constantly accessing UI elements. SO where do I go from here?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WPF, but from the message I think that changing the `STAThread` into a `MTAThread` should do the trick.

Comment: Call Thread.Join(0) somewhere in your long running task to allow message pumping

Answer (score -3):

Is it really that practical having so many visuals? If so, I would break the adding of the visuals down and do each in a separate message. In other words, use the Dispatcher to queue messages with an appropriate DispatcherPriority. Each message would be responsible for adding a small chunk of visuals from the total.

Comment: What do you mean by is it practical? Do I have other options?

Comment: I mean what could possibly require that many visuals? Perhaps it's possible that you could combine many visuals into a single one - you would need to elaborate on your specific scenario in order to determine this.

Comment: The answer "Is it really practical" doesn't solve anything here.

Comment: Did you read past the first sentence? You know, the one that assumes you *do* want that many visuals and starts with "If so".